# Show multiple Error result in Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I´m trying to show multiple error result at the same time(if there are more than 1 error result) in stead of showing one by one. To let user see the total error at once so they can fix at one time.

---

---

---

Here is my code:
**In main page**

```
<form id="iform" name="iform" onsubmit="validate(); return false">
<table width="509"><tr>
<td width="114">Name User</td>
<td width="177"><input type="text" name="owner" id="owner"/></td><td id="err1" width="202" style="color:red;"></td></tr><tr>
<td>Email </td><td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"/></td><td id="err2" style="color:red;"></td></tr><tr>
<td>Paypal</td>
<td><input type="email" name="paypal" id="paypal" /></td><td id="err3" style="color:red;"></td></tr><tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit"  value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'engine.php',
    data:{
    action:'add_user',  
    owner:document.iform.owner.value,
    email:document.iform.email.value,
    paypal:document.iform.paypal.value
    },
    type:'POST',
    success: function(data){

        if (data=="er1"){
        $("#err2").html("This email is already existed, please try another");
        return false;

        }
        if (data=="er2"){
        $("#err3").html("This paypal account is already existed, please try another");
        return false;

        }
        if (data=="ok"){
        location.reload();
        }

    }

    });
```

**in PHP**

```
$owner=$_POST[owner];
$email=$_POST[email];
$paypal=$_POST[paypal];

  $ss = $conn->prepare('select email_owner, paypal_owner from tb_owner');
  $ss->execute();
  $watashi=$ss->fetch();

if ($email==$watashi['email_owner']){
    echo"er1";

}

else if ($paypal==$watashi['paypal_owner']){
    echo"er2";

}

else{
/* EVEYTHING IS OK ->INSERT TO DATABASE */

 if ($stmt->rowCount()){ 
echo"ok";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is simple: [JSON][1].

In your PHP you should have something like:

```
$errors = array();
if($email==$watashi['email_owner']){
    $errors[] = "this email is already existed, try another";
}
if($paypal==$watashi['paypal_owner']){
    $errors[] = "this paypal is already existed, try another";
}

if(count($errors) > 0){
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'errors' => $errors));
```

And then you can read this in Javascript like this:

```
success: function(data){
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);



       if(json.status=== 'error'){
        $("#err2").html(json.errors[0]);
        $("#err3").html(json.errors[1]);

        return false;

         }


        if(json.status==="success"){
        location.reload();
        }
```

Comment: I have done something like this in ajax But nothing worked.
success: function(result){
    if(result.errors[error] === 'er1'){
    $("#err2").html("This email is already existed, please try another");

   return false;
     
    }
      if(result.errors[error] === 'er2'){
    $("#err3").html("This paypal is already existed, please try another");

   return false;
     
    }

Comment: I can't say for certain what you are having issues with. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` to make sure the data is all there.

Edit: Wait, I think I see the issue. You haven't converted the string `result` into an object. You need to add `var result = JSON.parse(result)`

Comment: I have tried many times now. No work, sorry :S don´t know why.
ANd when I put this line into ajax, everything stop work.
var result = JSON.parse(result)

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? What are they?

Comment: First of all I don´t think I did the correct way in php. Or I think the json encode you gave me is something I don´t use to. That´s why i don´t know what to do more.

Comment: Just research it a little. All it's doing is converting an object into a string and then back into an object. You could even setup your AJAX to expect a JSON response, but I was trying to give an answer that could easily fit into your code.

Comment: I have edit your code and now it worked. Thaks for help ! :):):)

Comment: No i have not console anything. I just looked around and found it.

Comment: One question please:
in php this line : $errors = array();
What is this stand for ? I have tried to remove it and everything still work fine. Seemed like this line is not necessary. Can you explain me why ?

Is that´s because of php version ?(I use php version 5.4)
And I remember your original code you wrote it with big A like this-->$errors = Array();

Comment: I'm simply initializing an empty array. It's not necessary, but it's good practice. (for some languages it is necessary)