# AJAX in Wordpress - loading some data in 2 different divs.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I use the following jquery code to retrieve post content via AJAX in Wordpress:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    data: ({action : 'ajax_page',
        post_id: page_id
    })
})
.done(function(data){
    $('#page-content').html(data);
});
```

the php function:

```
function ajax_page() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    $title = $post_data->post_title;
    $content = $post_data->post_content;
    echo $title;
    echo $content;
    die(); // remove trailing 0
}
```

But I would like to be able to load $title and $content in 2 different divs.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    data: ({action : 'ajax_page',
        post_id: page_id
    })
})
.done(function(data){
    $('#page-title').html(title);
    $('#page-content').html(data);
});
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Use JSON to easily read the data on both ends. I literally just wrote an answer to a similar question earlier today. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325704/show-multiple-error-result-in-ajax-jquery/26325941]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to seperate your ajax content in a clean way :

```
function ajax_page() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_data = get_post($post_id);
    $title = $post_data->post_title;
    $content = $post_data->post_content;

    echo json_encode(array($title,$content));
    die(); // remove trailing 0
}
```

And then get the two distinct return values from the array :

```
.done(function(data){
    var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('#page-title').html(myData[0]);
    $('#page-content').html(myData[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

return a json data which contains title and data in php function, try

```
echo json_encode(array('title'=>$title, 'data'=>$data));
```

Parse the json data in html and shown them you the divs;